# SpaCy, apply extensions during pipe

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

In SpaCy you can set extensions for documents like this:

```
Doc.set_extension('chapter_id', default='')

doc = nlp('This is my text')
doc._.chapter_id = 'This is my ID'
```

However, I'm having thousands of text files that should be handled by NLP. And SpaCy suggests to use `pipe` for this:

```
docs = nlp.pipe(array_of_texts)
```

How to apply my extension values during `pipe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to enable the `as_tuples` keyword argument on `nlp.pipe`, which lets you pass in a list of `(text, context)` tuples and will yield out `(doc, context)` tuples. So you could do something like this:

```
data = [('Some text', 1), ('Some other text', 2)]

def process_text(data):
    for doc, chapter_id in nlp.pipe(data, as_tuples=True):
        doc._.chapter_id = chapter_id
        yield doc
```

Comment: This works ok, when I pass only two values in tuple, but if there are more it throws error `too many values to unpack`. For example `for doc, chapter_id, story_id in nlp.pipe(data, as_tuples)`

Comment: Yes, that's correct, because the `as_tuples` option expects the data to always be a tuple of `(text, context)`, not more values. If you need to pass along more data, you could make `context` a list, tuple or a dictionary.